# Water heater leak into base. Concerned about moisture or mold

Tags: water-heater, mold, moisture

I am in process of replacing my 17 yo gas water heater. I am estimating it was leaking steady (maybe a drop or two a second) for around 24 hours before I got it shut off. Should I be concerned about the black parts on the wood below it? I’m going to replace the top and currently have a fan on it to dry it out. How long should I let it dry out?[image][image][image]

Comment: Minor leak not much to be concern with.  splash some beach on the wood and run the fan for a day or two.

Comment: @crip659 thank you

Comment: Where's the drain pan? Buy one for the next heater...

Comment: @Ecnerwal definitely. Got one ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Wood is damaged when it stays wet for long periods of time, like weeks and months. A 1-day incident will not be a problem. Let it dry naturally, you don't even need a fan, just time. Probably a day.

If mold was not an issue before the leak, it won't be now. Mold requires a wet environment that stays wet.